# Generate documentation for Akka HTTP's(Spray Routing DSL) Route

Tags: akka, spray, akka-http, spray-dsl

Is there custom extensions/directives for spray routing DSL/Akka HTTP which allow to generate documentation for given Route instance?

Answer (score 3):

Akka-Http evaluate their route structures lazily and hence this structure is not available upfront. Because of this, it is not as trivial to generate an API from a Route. Here are some relevant tickets:
https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/780
https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/16591